# Integrating libphonenumber in solr

Tags: solr

Any good strategy to integrate libphonenumber from google code in solr? Or just use it whit DIH and as a JavaScript function?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution:
[here](https://github.com/husart/SolrPhoneFilter)
I tried and it works fine, maybe this will helps others too.